# Echo values from a column and transfer it in an array

Tags: php, pdo

Hello so basically I am sending messages to different cell phone numbers in my table and my current code is:

```
<?php
    require 'dbc.php';
    $securimage = new Securimage();
    include "smsGateway.php";
    $smsGateway = new SmsGateway('email@gmail.com', 'pword');

        $stmt = $dbc->query("SELECT * FROM tblcontactlist");
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $message = "Hello world!";
        $deviceID = 123;
        $number = $row['contactNumber'];
        $result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToNumber($number, $message, $deviceID);
        }
?>
```

What I am doing is echoing every number and sending message to each of it.

What I wanted to do is to put all the cell phone numbers in an array and the code will look like this:

```
$message = "Hello world!";
$deviceID = 123;
$numbers = ['+44771232343', '+44771232344'];
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToManyNumber($numbers, $message, $deviceID);
```

But instead of encoding every cell phone number into that array, I want to loop every number in my table and put the column values into that array.

My table is named `tblcontaclist` and the column name that contains the numbers is `contactNumber`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: It's second time i think that we are telling you put your effort what you did and your expected output:-

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Improved it you may check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$numbers = array();
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
$numbers[] = $row['contactNumber'];
}
$message = "Hello world!";
$deviceID = 123;
$result = $smsGateway->sendMessageToManyNumber($numbers, $message, $deviceID);
```